# express setImmediate(function () { error

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Im busy with a chat app with nodejs 6 socketio 1.7.2  express 4.14.1.
i can run node index.js but as soon as i access my page simplechat.html
it throws the below error. Please help

> /root/Chat/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1013
>       setImmediate(function () {
>       ^ ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined
>       at Array.onfinish [as 0] (/root/Chat/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1013:5)
>       at listener (/root/Chat/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:169:15)
>       at onFinish (/root/Chat/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:100:5)
>       at callback (/root/Chat/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
>       at ServerResponse.onevent (/root/Chat/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:93:5)
>       at ServerResponse.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._finish (http.js:837:8)
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (http.js:822:10)
>       at onend (stream.js:66:10)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)

**Package json file**

```
    {
    "name": "Chat",
    "version": "0.0.0",
     "description": "ERROR: No README.md file found!",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
     "repository": "",
     "author": "",
     "license": "BSD",
     "dependencies": {
     "express": "~4.14.1",
     "socket.io": "~1.7.2"
   }
```

**Index.js File**

```
  // We need to use the express framework: have a real web server that knows       how to send mime types etc.

   var express=require('express');
  // Init globals variables for each module required
  var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

  // Indicate where static files are located  
  //app.configure(function () {  
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));  
  //});  

   // launch the http server on given port
  server.listen(8000,'***.***.**.**');
  console.log('Server running at http://***.***.***.**:8000/');
  // routing
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/simpleChat.html');
   });

    // usernames which are currently connected to the chat
    var usernames = {};

           io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
         socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
       // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
          io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
        });

      // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
      socket.on('adduser', function(username){
     // we store the username in the socket session for this client
     socket.username = username;
     // add the client's username to the global list
     usernames[username] = username;
     // echo to client they've connected
     socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
     // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
      socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has   connected');
     // update the list of users in chat, client-side
     io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
       });

      // when the user disconnects.. perform this
      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
     // update list of users in chat, client-side
      io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
      // echo globally that this client has left
       socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has            disconnected');
        });
         });
```

**SimpleChat.html**

```
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var socket = io.connect(); // we might pass the URL of the WS server as parameter here

        // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
        socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
        });

        // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body 
        socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data);
        });

        // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
        socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
        $('#users').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
        });
        });

        // on load of page
        $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
        var message = $('#data').val();
        $('#data').val('');
        // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
        socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#datasend').focus().click();
        }
        });
        });

        </script>
        <div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
        <b>USERS</b>
        <div id="users"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
        <div id="conversation"></div>
        <input id="data" style="width:200px;">
        <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send">
        </div>
```

Comment: change line var app = express() to var app = express(''express")()

Comment: at owaishanif786 sorry that didnt work man.